# prevent button press until radio button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that is created on each slide in a quiz game. Radio buttons containing the answer choices are appended from an object onto each slide as you cycle through the questions. I want to require that a radio button be clicked on before you can access the nextQuestion button. You can find the .append() on line 5 of the code below (inside of the loadQuestion function). What method would be the best way to achieve the desired result? If you need more of the code, let me know.

```
var loadQuestion = function (){
        $('.question-name').html(name + (qnum) +"/"+ total);
        $('.question').html(questions[count].question);
        for(var i=0; i<questions[count].options.length; i++) {
            $('.inputs').append('<input type="radio" name="question" value="'+questions[count].options[i]+'">'+questions[count].options[i]+'<br>')
        }
    };

    /*--- First Question ---*/
    var name = "Question ";
    var qnum = 1;
    var count = 0;
    var total = questions.length;
    loadQuestion();

    /*--- When the Next Question Button is Hit ---*/
    nextQuestion.click(function() {
        $('.inputs').html("");
        qnum++;
        count++;
        if (qnum <= 4) {
            loadQuestion();
        } else if (qnum == 6) {
            $('.question-name').html("Your Score:");
            $('.question').html("You got X out of 5 questions correct!");
            nextQuestion.html("Home Screen").click(function() {
                location.reload();
            });
        } else if (qnum == 5){
            loadQuestion();
            $('.next-question').html("Get Score!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: one way to do it is, in your click function check if radio button is selected, if false return else continue with what you are doing now

Comment: Just check if a radiobutton is checked.
if ($('input[name="question"]:checked').length > 0) { //DOSTUFF

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nextButton').attr('disabled', true);//disable the button by default on page load
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            $('#nextButton').attr('disabled', false);//enable only when the checkbox is checked
        }
    });
});
```

I hope this helps!

Security note: Anybody can remove the disabled attribute from the button tag using developer tools in the browser. Use the backend to validate the checkbox value.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to go about this:

> "Prevent button press until radio is selected"

From a ui/ux perspective your request raises the following question: *"If the user isn't supposed to click on the button until the radio is selected, why is the button available for them to press before the radio is selected?"* So, let's start there.

```
//pseudo-code - use delegate binding '.on()' for dynamically generated elements

$('.inputs').on('click', 'input[name="question"]', function({
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#nextButton').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#nextButton').attr('disabled', true);
  } /*... snip ...*/ 
}));
```

Or, you could generate the `nextButton` after an answer is selected much in the same way that you are currently generating the radio button - just remember to use **delegate event binding**. This is probably the "better way" because as has already been pointed out by @zadd, the `disabled` property can be circumvented.

Without reinventing the wheel, you could also just check to see if there's a radio selected when the button is pressed.

```
// pseudo-code again
nextQuestion.click(function() {

   if($('input[name="question"]:checked').length > 0){
      // checked!!! go do stuff!!!
   } else {
     // not checked! i should probably throw an alert or something...
     alert('please answer the question before proceeding...');
   }

});
```